# Cypress Test runner--- can I make the warning message for "Download the React DevTools for a better development experience" go away?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I am using Cypress to test a React app.

is there a way to make this warning message in my console go away:

```
Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: ...
```

you will note that I see this warning only when running the controlled Chrome instance, not when looking at the same app in the normal Chrome browser. (As well, I *do* have the React dev tools installed and activated in Chrome so it seems this message is a side effect of the Cypress test-runner)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this regex to the DevTools [console filter input](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/reference#regex):

```
-/React.DevTools/
```